# Create record instance with default values

Tags: f#

I have a record type:

```
type Person = 
   {
       Name : string
       Age : int
   }
```

And I need a function which returns new instances of this record with default (in C# point of view) fields.

I can do it like this:

```
let f = 
  {
     Name = ""
     Age = 0
  }
```

but I would like to avoid all fields enumeration and use something like this:

```
let f = new Person
```

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used `Unchecked.defaultof<'t>`.  However be aware that F# records are immutable, so this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Hmm... defaultof<Person> returns null.  It is not answer to this question, but it is excellent solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790446/what-if-the-best-way-to-return-option-types-by-wcf-service my related problem ! Thanks

Comment: I think there might be a bit of the X-Y problem here.  You really don't want to be using records in the situation that they can be empty as they are immutable

Comment: The correct capitalization should be `Unchecked.defaultof<'t>` (at least as of today 2022-01-23).

Answer (score 22):

F# allows adding methods/properties to records and discriminated unions:

```
type Person =
{
    Name: string
    Age: int
}
with
    static member Default = { Name = ""; Age = 0 }
```

In FSI:

```
 > Person.Default;;
    val it : Person = {Name = "";
                       Age = 0;}
```