# What if the best way to return Option types by WCF service

Tags: wcf, f#

I have a WCF method which search the record in database and return Some(object) if the record exists and None if it doesn't.

As I see I can't call the method which returns `Type option` through WCF (I get exception).

What is the best way to design WCF services in F# in this way?

For example, I can return empty `Type`

```
Person
  {  
      Name = ""
      Age = 0
      // ....
  }
```

if the record doesn't exist in DB, but I am looking for the best ideas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A WCF service, just like a RESTful service, exposes an API that can be accessed by remote clients. These clients need not even be written in .NET, but could be Java clients, or written in a completely different language, for all we know.

The entire point of SOAP and REST is to enable those interoperability scenarios, but that also means that services may [share schema and contract, but not class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954638.aspx) (or any other type, for that matter).

A few years ago, I wrote an article called *[At the Boundaries, Applications are Not Object-Oriented](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AttheBoundaries,ApplicationsareNotObject-Oriented)*, but you can take that article, and replace *Object-Oriented* with *Functional:* *At the Boundaries, Applications are Not Functional (Programming)*.

Even if you *could* somehow serialize option types in WCF, you'd be advised not to do so, because clients may not understand what it means, or be able to handle that serialized format in any meaningful way.

In the end, an *option* can be viewed as a **constrained collection** with the constraint that it can hold either 0 or 1 element. You can't model that *constraint* when you return data over an interoperable service, but you can still return a collection/array.

That's what I sometimes do: return an array with either no element, or a single element. Most clients understand that.

When building RESTful services, you have the better option of returning **404** (Not found) when a resource doesn't exist, but I'm not sure there's a good way to do this with SOAP.

With SOAP, though, you can define data structures using XSD, so you might be able to use [xsd.choice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256109) to model a data structure that can be either *none* or *some*.

Comment: And of course the billion dollar mistake also comes into play here. A lot of wsdl/xsd's with xsi:nullable around as a rich mans Option...